# Why don't cameras have automatic eyepiece covers?

Tags: dslr, viewfinder, slr, camera-design, eyepiece

The question is clear and I am not sure how to further explain it. Why don't cameras have internal automatic eyepiece covers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "internal automatic eyepiece cover" I assume you mean something to block the light instead of something to protect the eyepiece glass from scratches.

There are no cameras with an "Automatic Eyepiece Cover" but some Pro level cameras have a manual eyepiece shutter to block off light during long exposures when your eye is not covering the viewfinder.  This prevents exposure errors due to light entering the viewfinder.

Canon EOS-1Dx

[image]

Canon A-1 
[image]

Other Cameras use a rubber piece that snaps onto the viewfinder to block the light.

[image]

[image]

Comment: All good info, but doesn't really address the question, which is *why* an automatic cover doesn't exist.

Comment: What is your idea of an " internal automatic eyepiece cover" ?  Is it a simple user activated eyepiece shutter like some cameras already have?  Or is it a fully automatic device that activates anytime you remove your eye from the viewfinder?

Comment: It's not really automatic if the user has to activate it. I expect OP means a cover that moves into position when the shutter is released.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've accepted your answer because it shows they existed. I meant something like the Canon A-1 above. or something which activates automatically when face/eye is not close to the eyepiece. there are sensors for turning off the display when face is close, why not this?

Answer (score 4):

Because it would add expense and complexity, and most consumers don't request it.